# Forward all subdomains to main domain without changing URL?

Tags: domain, redirection, subdomain, cname

I just bought a domain, I want to redirect all of the subdomains to the main one but without the user really "knowing", if that makes sense. I use GitHub pages for hosting.
What I need is as such:

- User goes to sub.domain.com
- Actually sees domain.com's HTML, modified a bit using JS to suit "sub".
- URL bar stays the same

I've tried adding a CNAME from * to domain.com, but I get a 404 from github when I try accessing any subdomain. What am I doing wrong? I'm using namecheap.

Comment: Shouldn't the [official documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) cover this? It's also unclear how GitHub would be related to this when you're just talking about `domain.com`. All in all you should consider adding more context on what you actually tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I tried adding a CNAME from *.mydomain.com to mydomain.com. and that didn't work out.
I think what I'm trying is really to just serve mydomain.com/index.html for every subdomain that was entered, with the URL still appearing as sub.mydomain.com. Will a URL redirection fit my needs here?

Comment: The `*` in "CNAME from *.mydomain.com" means a real `*` character or just an example for the purpose of this question? Because using a wildchar when specifying a CNAME record for a subdomain won't work, you have to specify each concrete subdomain (at least with most DNS managers I've encountered with).

Comment: @TomasVarga I did try using it as a wildcard, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

*Answer as added to original question by OP:*

I ended up using a masked redirect so all traffic will go the main page, then used window.referrer to determine if I was in an iframe (and if so, get the outside URL) and act accordingly.